# Rails belongs_to does not set foreign key id with custom class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

I have my models setup like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => 'author_id'
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Assuming:

```
p = Post.first # just any post instance
a = User.first # any user instance
```

Now this piece of code is acting very weird

```
p.author = a
```

After setting the author, the attribute `author_id` of the post should be set to the id of the user. But this isn't happening.

I tried using models with `belongs_to` that does not have the `class_name` parameter and everything works as expected.

Now, one more thing that makes it weirder is that when I change the association to `belongs_to :author, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'author_id'`, it surprisingly works.

Is this a bug in Rails 3.0.9? Shouldn't the foreign key parameter be unnecessary because as the docs say, its default value is the name of the association appended with `_id`.

Also note that even without `:foreign_key => 'author_id'`, everything else regarding the association works as expected. (Like fetching the associated model) The only thing not working is the setter method not setting the foreign key.

I know I could just do `p.author_id = a.id` or just add `:foreign_key` params to all my associations with `class_name`, but I prefer the more elegant syntax of `p.author = a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading through lots of Rails code and tracing here's what I found:

This bug exists because of the gem `composite_primary_keys` which overrode the default rails `reflection.rb`.

I will have to check how they implemented the `primary_key_name` and `derive_primary_key_name` methods.

It was quite a bit of time wasted on this silly bug, but at least I got to learn a lot about ActiveRecord's internals.